# html code not running jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML code is not running ! Here item.m = "some html code", but it is showing as plain text, not as running html . I am confused what to do now..

```
$("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").append('<div class="chatboxmessage"><span class="chatboxmessagefrom">'+item.f+':&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="chatboxmessagecontent">'+$.parseHTML(item.m)+'</span></div>');
```

Complete Code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "chat.php?action=chatheartbeat",
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {

    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        if (item)   { // fix strange ie bug

            chatboxtitle = item.f;

            if ($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).length <= 0) {
                createChatBox(chatboxtitle);
            }
            if ($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('display') == 'none') {
                $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('display','block');
                restructureChatBoxes();
            }

            if (item.s == 1) {
                item.f = username;
            }

            if (item.s == 2) {
                $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").append('<div class="chatboxmessage"><span class="chatboxinfo">'+item.m+'</span></div>');
            } else {
                newMessages[chatboxtitle] = true;
                newMessagesWin[chatboxtitle] = true;
                $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").append('<div class="chatboxmessage"><span class="chatboxmessagefrom">'+item.f+':&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="chatboxmessagecontent">'+$.parseHTML(item.m)+'</span></div>');
            }

            $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").scrollTop($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent")[0].scrollHeight);
            itemsfound += 1;
        }
    });
```

Response data is `<a href='../chat/file/6717_1_work.txt'>work.txt</a>` but it is showing as text instead of hyper-link.

Comment: Do you get what you're expecting when you `console.log( item.f )` ?

Comment: Can you give us the response data ?

Comment: Hi Response data is <a href='../chat/file/6717_1_work.txt'>work.txt</a> but it is showing as text instead of hyper-link.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `parseHTML` function? Doesn't seem necessary to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/konp7vga/)

Apparently you need to remove the $.parseHTML and it will work

```
$("div").append('<span class="chatboxmessagecontent">'+("<a href='../chat/file/6717_1_work.txt'>work.txt</a>")+'</span></div>');
```

As you can see with your code in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/konp7vga/1/) it is not working with **$.parseHTML**